# Google Search Appliance Sharepoint connector

Tags: google-search, google-search-api, google-search-appliance

How is GSA SharePoint Connector, I am trying to integrate sharepoint connector in our search application to bring sharepoint contents in the search. There are lot of issues that we have come across in the process. I wanted to know if the sharepoint connector is the write choice, as our business has now started to doubt the credibility of the search results. Here are list of issues that i am facing:

1. Sporadic search results
2. Crawling non crawlable sites and its data intermittently
3. We are getting ACL with the URL sporadically.

We are using SAML for user authentication and ACL for early binding. 
We have implemented connector authentication in ULF
We have increased the timeouts
None of the above adjustment seems to be working as desired by functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues you are probably running in to here but unless you give a lot more detail it's not going to be easy to explain them to you.

Start by making sure you're using FQDNs to access Sharepoint.

The Sharepoint connector does work but you have to configure it correctly.
It sounds like you might want to get in touch with the partner that supplied your GSA for some help.

Answer (score 0):

The Sharepoint connector for the Google Search Appliance is supported by Google.  You can create a ticket with Google support and they'll be able to dig deep into this.  Unless you provide additional information it's difficult to suggest another alternative.